# Multiple columns in Table-view (SwiftUI)?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI and was going to try out the Table-view, but no matter what I try I only get a single column view. I have studied some code samples, and I can't see what is wrong with my code. Why do I only get a single column? I have also tried setting the width on each TableColumn() to a smaller value, but I only get a single column view no matter what...

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyItem: Identifiable {
    var id: String { firstname + " " + lastname }
        
    let firstname: String
    let lastname: String
}

let data: [MyItem] = [
    MyItem(firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe"),
    MyItem(firstname: "Peter", lastname: "Pan")
]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Table(data) {
            
            TableColumn("Firstname", value: \.firstname)
            TableColumn("Lastname", value: \.lastname)
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the designed/defined behaviour on an iPhone. If you build your code for iPad you will see two columns.

If you want to force two columns on an iPhone you can use SwiftUI's Grid.